# Scope of Python Class Variable?

Tags: python, class, scope

Are class variables essentially global variables?

Consider this example, in bar.py:

```
class Bar(object):
    b = {}
```

then in foo.py:

```
def foo1():
    import bar
    bar.Bar.b["key"] = "foo1"


def foo2():
    import bar
    print bar.Bar.b.get("key", "foo2")

foo1()
foo2()
```

The "key" value is persistently "foo1."

For my purposes this seems like a global variable.  But why isn't the class variable being reset or deleted between the calls to foo1 and foo2?

Comment: @mgilson I am asking why isn't the variable being garbage collected between the two calls; that link seems to be talking about the difference between the instance and class variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a class attribute.  In your case, the dict is bound to the class `Bar`.  Everytime you import `bar`, you get the same class `bar.Bar` (after all, it is in the `bar`'s global namespace), and consequentially, you get the same dict `bar.Bar.b`.

If you want each `Bar` instance to have a different dict, you need to make an instance:

```
class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = {}
```

And then:

```
def foo1():
    import bar
    bar.Bar().b["key"] = "foo1"


def foo2():
    import bar
    print bar.Bar().b.get("key", "foo2")

foo1()
foo2()
```

---

As far as why the module `bar` isn't being garbage collected, when you import something, python stores a reference to that module (see [`sys.modules`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.modules)).  The next time you import that module, python picks out the proper item from `sys.modules` and gives you a reference to it.  There are a few reasons for this.

- Efficiency -- Why re-evaluate code you've already evaluated?
- Sane behavior

Imagine a module with a special value:

```
# mod.py
CONSTANT = object()
```

now you want to use that in `foo.py` and `bar.py`.

```
# bar.py
import mod
def bar():
    return mod.CONSTANT

# foo.py
import mod
import bar
if bar.bar() is mod.CONSTANT:
    do_something()
```

If the import wasn't cached, then `mod.CONSTANT` *could* be different in `foo` and in `bar` which would be very surprising.

Comment: Thank you.  I was concerned about it being garbage collected because there was no explicit reference.  When will bar's global namespace be deleted?  During the python shutdown process?

Comment: @E.Beach -- Ahh, I understand your question now (and the reason for the function local imports).  I've edited